Duplicated add style in head when use ConfigProvider custom theme
I use ConfigProvider in my app and i custom theme for new font family, but it add 2 style in head tag for 1 component
const designSystem = {
  "token": {
    "fontFamily": "Archivo, Exo",
  }
}

<ConfigProvider theme={designSystem}>
 <div className="main-container">
    <div className="card-top-container">
        <Skeleton.Image active={true} />
    </div>
    <div className="card-main-container">
        <Space size={16} direction="vertical">
            <Skeleton.Input active={true} block={true} />
            <Skeleton.Input active={true} block={true} />
        </Space>
    </div>
</ConfigProvider>

After build: two style for skeleton and two style for skeleton loading
two style for skeleton loading
How to fix it to add 1 style skeleton had apply new theme

I think this is expected, there will be a string of hash characters in classname, used to distinguish the scope of style effectiveness. Suppose you have multiple CP nesting, if you modify the token, the classname hash of the component it wraps will be different, so it can take effect accurately.
